# Linking quaver and semiquaver beams over a rest with LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, rests, beaming

I am transcribing the *Sentimental Tango for four hands* by Vasha Azarashvili. And I'd like to obtain this:

[image: A quaver and a semiquaver beamed together over a rest]

But my code (in Italian, but surely you get the point)

```
\language "italiano"

<sib re sol>8_. r16 <sib re sol>_.
```

produces this:

[image: A quaver and a semiquaver with a rest in between]

How can I get the former?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use '[' and ']' to define the a beam group (as explained in the LilyPond [documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/beams#manual-beams))

`<sib re sol>8_.[ r16 <sib re sol>_.]`

Any reason you write `_.` instead of the neutral `-.` here?  When pitches are such that the stem is picked the other way round, a hard-coded `_.` will stay below the chord and look awkward.

Comment: Thank you @user97997! It works neatly and on why I use _., is just out of ignorance :). I fixed it as well. Thanks again!